# Bar plot options with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am actually trying to do a graph with ggplot2 but I'd like to add some options (colors, legend...).

Here is my code :

```
ggplot(FINAL, aes(x = as.factor(gender), y=overtreatment)) +
stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="bar") +
facet_grid(. ~ treatment) +
theme_grey() +
xlab("Treatment") +
ylab("OT") + 
scale_fill_grey() +
theme(strip.background = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = "white"))
```

And here the actual output.

[image]

Could you please indicate me how to change the name of 1 and 2 (without changing in it the dataframe) and how to add colours to this ?

I tried this

```
 ggplot(FINAL, aes(x = as.factor(gender), y=overtreatment, colour=Treatment))
```

But it applies the color only to the outline of the figure.

Comment: For colour you must use `fill = Treatment`. As for the labels, maybe `aes(x = factor(gender, labels = c("Female", "Male")), etc)`.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(FINAL)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(FINAL, 20))`.

Answer (score 2):

To change the color of the bars you need `fill = Treatment`.

To change the labels on the x axis you need `scale_x_discrete(labels = your_labels)`. [See here.](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/2.2.1/topics/scale_x_discrete)

So your code will look like:

```
ggplot(FINAL, aes(x = as.factor(gender), y=overtreatment, fill= Treatment)) +
scale_x_discrete(labels = your_labels) + 
...
```